# postmaster.pid permission denied CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, centos7

Postgres 9.2 on CentOS 7.

After "su - postgres" I installed using

pg-ctl initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/data

which ran fine.

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl start postgresql
Job for postgresql.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@server ~]# systemctl status postgresql.service
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-11-27 13:48:57 EST; 9s ago
  Process: 3262 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3256 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network pg_ctl[3262]: pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
[root@server ~]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Fri 2015-11-27 13:29:37 EST, end at Fri 2015-11-27 13:48:57 EST. --
Nov 27 13:48:35 server.company.network sudo[3228]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Nov 27 13:48:35 server.company.network sudo[3228]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [myuserid]
Nov 27 13:48:46 server.company.network sudo[3230]: myuserid : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/myuserid ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
Nov 27 13:48:46 server.company.network su[3234]: (to root) myuserid on pts/0
Nov 27 13:48:46 server.company.network su[3234]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by myuserid(uid=0)
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network pg_ctl[3262]: pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Nov 27 13:48:57 server.company.network systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
```

When I "su - postgres" I can "touch" the file, "ls" the file, "rm" /var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid.  Permissions on data are 700 postgres:postgres.  pgsql is a symlink to /data0/postgres and postgres is 700 postgres:postgres.

ADDITIONS:

I forgot to mention that after having this problem, I replaced the commands for ExecStartPre and ExecStart with shell scripts that wrote the user, primary group, PGDATA, and PGPORT values to a file.  They were all correct.  The start still died on postmaster.pid .

The postgresql.service file:

```
[root@server /]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
# It's not recommended to modify this file in-place, because it will be
# overwritten during package upgrades.  If you want to customize, the
# best way is to create a file "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service",
# containing
#       .include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
#       ...make your changes here...
# For more info about custom unit files, see
# http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_customize_a_unit_file.2F_add_a_custom_unit_file.3F

# For example, if you want to change the server's port number to 5433,
# create a file named "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service" containing:
#       .include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
#       [Service]
#       Environment=PGPORT=5433
# This will override the setting appearing below.

# Note: changing PGPORT or PGDATA will typically require adjusting SELinux
# configuration as well; see /usr/share/doc/postgresql-*/README.rpm-dist.

# Note: do not use a PGDATA pathname containing spaces, or you will
# break postgresql-setup.

# Note: in F-17 and beyond, /usr/lib/... is recommended in the .include line
# though /lib/... will still work.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Port number for server to listen on
Environment=PGPORT=5432

# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/data

# Where to send early-startup messages from the server (before the logging
# options of postgresql.conf take effect)
# This is normally controlled by the global default set by systemd
# StandardOutput=syslog

# Disable OOM kill on the postmaster
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o "-p ${PGPORT}" -w -t 300
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA} -s

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Show `postgresql.service` unit file

Comment: I forgot to mention that after having this problem, I replaced the commands for ExecStartPre and ExecStart with shell scripts that wrote the user, primary group, PGDATA, and PGPORT values to a file.  They were all correct.  The start still died on postmaster.pid .

Comment: Try add `PIDFile=/other/location/postmaster.pid` to `[service]` section.Make sure Yu have full access to `/other/location/` dir

Comment: I put "PIDFile=/data0/oldpostgres/postmaster.pid" between "Type" and "User".  It is being ignored and still failing to open "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid" .  oldpostgres is a directory set up to receive a dump file from another server.  There is no other installation of Postgres on this server.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  After running initdb, I copied the data directory to the other drive.  With SELinux, the FILETYPE switches to the target parent directory FILETYPE.  I tried to semanage the directory, but that wasn't working.  So I started over again and moved the data directory instead, which maintained the FILETYPE.